# IIS Manager Extensibility - Editing Collections

Tags: iis, plugins

I'm currently trying to write a plugin for IIS 7 Manager to provide some custom configuration. I've successfully populated a PropertyGridObject with some basic data types (a few strings and ints) but I'm having problems trying to edit a Collection object. I should point out that I'm successfully reading and writing the basic settings from the web.config file.

I do see an ellipsis button on the grid object and it launches the "Object Collection Editor" but then I can't add or edit any entries.

The standard "Configuration Editor" in IIS Manager shows a good example of a nice dialog in section "system.webServer/httpErrors" of what I'm trying to achieve. Has anyone got an experience on doing this?

In general, I've found the examples on the web for these plugins to be few-and-far between and too simple. Is it just me looking in the wrong place or is M$ keeping the details of this quiet? Would I be better off writing an ASP page to modify my web.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found some good examples on writing plugins for IIS 7 Manager in a book called "Professional IIS 7 and ASP.NET Integrated Programming" by Dr. Shahram Khosravi.

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-IIS-ASP-NET-Integrated-Programming/dp/0470152532/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1304032628&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470152532)

If you buy the book, or find the samples on the Wiley website, you should look at Chapter 7.